# Meaning of "Darf ich euch vorstellen?"

Tags: meaning

I'm a beginner in German. The google translation translates "Darf ich euch vorstellen?"  to "May I introduce you?"
Is it "May I introduce you (to others)?" Please somebody confirm it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the context you can translate

> May I introduce you?

to

> Darf ich **Sie** [mit Herrn Kowalski] bekannt machen?
>   Darf ich **Sie** [Herrn Kowalski] vorstellen?
>   *(Sie: no friend[s] or relative[s])*
>
> Darf ich **euch** bekannt machen?
>     Darf ich **euch** [Frau Raddatz] vorstellen?
>   *(euch: friends or relatives)*
>
> Darf ich **dich** [meiner neuen Freundin / meinem Onkel] vorstellen?
>   *(dich: friend or relative)*

**Concerning your title example**

> Darf ich euch vorstellen?
>   *means*
>   May I introduce you to others?

but

> Darf ich euch Frau Raddatz vorstellen?
>   *means*
>   May I introduce you to Mrs Raddatz?
>   *but can also mean*
>   May I introduce Mrs Raddatz to you?

Comment: Ok, My question was if it means "May I introduce you?" or "May I introduce myself?" but from your answer I understand it means all "May I introduce you to someone (for example to Mr. Kowalski).". Danke.

Comment: @Chan Kim: Right, there is no case for _»May I introduce myself?«_ Please see also my updated answer.

Comment: Oh, that was very helpful. Especially the last example. Thanks!